# storage of about 1MB for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension which needs to auto-save the text of a hmtl5 content editable section. My estimation is that the space need would be about 1MB. How do I approach this? Does the localStorage.setItem work in a chrome extension?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Answer (score 1):

In a Chrome Extension, you can use the storage API. It can handle a couple MBs, make sure to add the permission to the manifest file (this one won't prompt users to accept it)

```
...
"permissions": [
    "storage"
],
```

To save the user's input:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
    auto_saved_text: 'text entered by the user'
}, function() { ... })
```

Then to retrieve it later:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('auto_saved_text', function(values) {
    if('auto_saved_text' in values) {
        // values.auto_saved_text contains the value
    }
    else {
        // The value has never been saved before
    }
});
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Got it. For saving and and retrieve you've used the function (). What is this for? Is this optional?

Comment: It is a callback function, the storage API is asynchronous, which means `chrome.storage.get(...)` doesn't return the values you want right away. It somewhat works like an ajax call. It is optional when you set a value, but recommended to detect errors. Read the documentation, it contains exemples and useful tips.

Comment: Based on my understanding I wrote the below code. Tied the saveNotes function to a keyup event. When I reopen the extension, the textarea isn't populated with the text.

function saveNotes(){
var a = document.getElementById ("notes").innter.Html;
chrome.storage.local.set({'value': a});
}


function main()
{
  document.getElementById("notes").inner.Html= chrome.storage.local.get({'value': a});

}

Comment: I tried your code but it throws an error. I switched to textarea instead of content-editable section.

screenshot: http://ibin.co/2C1GrqXcPrMf

Comment: You can't use addEventListener on a querySelector's return value. It's an array of nodes. You can use getElementById instead. Also instead of using innerHTML, if should be docuent.getElementById('notes').value = results.notes;

Comment: Huh? You can use addEventListener on a querySelector's return value. The array of nodes is from querySelectorAll.